# launching putty from browser also opens up cmd.exe

Tags: html, browser, putty, openssh

I was trying to launch PUTTY from web browser while, I was able to achieve this after reading this post " http://johnsofteng.wordpress.com/2009/05/12/launch-putty-from-browser/ " but when i click on any ssh:// link both command prompt(cmd.exe) and putty.exe are opening up.I do not want command prompt(cmd.exe) to openup instead only putty.exe should launch.

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command window runs you batch file, you can achieve what you want with the following:

add start (https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx?mfr=true) to the batch file call to start putty, ie:

```
start /b "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" %extract%
```

this allows the batch file to close once putty has launched, rather than waiting for it to exit.

To prevent the command window appearing in the first place take a look at this answer https://superuser.com/a/443181 and the thread it is in in general

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
CD C:\Program Files\PuTTY
start putty.exe %extract%
exit
```

instead of :

```
"C:\Program Files\PUTTY\putty.exe" %extract% exit
```

Comment: hey have tried this but it is not working ,i think cmd prompt becomes inactive after launching putty.exe.thats why it does not read the exit command.My bash file looks like this :  @echo off
set var=%1
set extract=%var:~6,-1%
"C:\Program Files\PUTTY\putty.exe" %extract% 
exit